# Using Reports with Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, report

I am working on Flex 4 and I want to use reports with my Flex project. 
Is there any way to do the same? I mean any report library provided by Flex or any 3rd party application integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please clarify which reports did you mean?

if you mean something like Crystal Reports like in some C++ IDE look in this side http://forums.adobe.com/message/2719429

If you mean some TDD Reports look to Flex Unit Testing Reports

If you mean some custom reports creating with charting and etc. use some flare lib and charting components of flex SDK.

Let us know.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for the reply... We have not decided anything which reports we would be using? We are still looking for the same. Actually its my new Web project and I dont have any idea about what reports people normally use in their Flex project?

Comment: It would be very great if you can guide me about which reports are mostly used?

Comment: tell me your goals. so I could select some of report which are the best for you.